# Combining categories and statistical significance

Tags: regression, categorical-data

When we have a regression, say, with a categorical predictor with multiple levels, and for whatever reason we combine categories, say, due to small cell counts, how can we tell what effect this will have on the *overall significance* of the categorical predictor, if any? Say you run a likelihood ratio test on the model with and without this categorical predictor, and you get one p-value.  Will this p-value change when running the same test after combining categories?

Is there any theory that tells you whether overall significance is affected? I can't find any references on this...would appreciate some insight.

I am inclined to think that merging categories changes overall significance.  To wit,

```
mydata <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)

my.mod1 <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial") # with rank
my.mod2 <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa, data = mydata, family = "binomial") # without rank

anova(my.mod1, my.mod2, test="LRT")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: admit ~ gre + gpa + rank
Model 2: admit ~ gre + gpa
Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1       394     458.52                          
2       397     480.34 -3  -21.826 7.088e-05 ***
```

And now I merge categories of rank:

```
levels(mydata$rank)[levels(mydata$rank)=="4"] <- "1"

my.mod1 <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = "binomial") # with rank
my.mod2 <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa, data = mydata, family = "binomial") # without rank

anova(my.mod1, my.mod2, test="LRT")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: admit ~ gre + gpa + rank
Model 2: admit ~ gre + gpa
Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
 1       395     473.55                       
 2       397     480.34 -2  -6.7931  0.03349 *
```

Not sure if this is reasonable... it seems to imply that merging categories can affect your conclusion about the significance of a predictor...

Comment: If you have three levels A, B and C, and there's a difference between A and B, but B=C, then merging A and B is going to "water down" the difference between AB and C. If the difference is smaller then the statistic you calculate is likely to be smaller, and the $p$-value will increase. It seems like it might also potentially increase the amount of variance, which could also decrease the test statistic and increase $p$.

Comment: doesn't that then imply that merging categories can change whether you conclude a predictor is significant??

Comment: It could potentially take a $p$-value from below your $\alpha$ level to being above it, but obviously $p$-values lose meaning when you start exploring the data like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your statement "p-values lose meaning..."?

Comment: Better, more thorough, elaborations can be found elsewhere but one aspect of a $p$-value is the idea that it's telling you the probability of observing something given a variety of factors that you decided _a priori_. If you change the way your categorical variable is coded by merging categories then that's something that was not fixed _a priori_.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. One last question.  Suppose you run some sort of variable selection to find significant categorical covariates.  Then, you merge categories in order to increase the precision of your estimates.  In light of what we have been discussing, could this possibly be problematic, since the new coding may make the significant variable from the selection procedure insignificant?

Comment: I don't know. You may want to consider asking that as a new question.

Comment: @Ian_Fin The P-value loses its commonly expected relationship with the false positive error rate of a test in circumstances of exploratory data analysis, but it certainly does not lose its meaning. It remains a relative ranking of the strangeness of the observed data relative to the expectations from the statistical model, and it remains an index of the evidence in the data against the null hypothesised value of the parameter of interest according to0t he statistical model. The idea that a P-value has to be related to the error rate in order to be useful or valid is false.

Comment: What effect any reactive changing of categories will have on a *calculated* p-value depends on the calculation.  What we can say generally is that no formal test in existence can anticipate your reactions to the initial results.  Therefore it would be incorrect to interpret any subsequent p-value calculations as having any valid relationship to the properties of the procedure you have followed (such as its false positive rate).